# How to create dd/mm/yyyy date format using DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to create a `DateTime` object from format `dd/mm/yyyy H:i:s`, then I type:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(
  'dd/mm/yyyy H:i:s', 
  '01/02/2018 00:00:00'
);
```

And the result is `false`. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Double d, double m, quadruple y...

Comment: See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to correct your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check the [PHP: DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for proper formatting.

- `d` will try to match `7` or `07` day
- `m` will match `1` or `01` month
- `Y` will match `2017` (four-digit year)

The format string you should be using is `d/m/Y H:i:s`

#### Corrected:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y H:i:s', 
    '01/02/2018 00:00:00'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your Question on Why**

The reason why it happened, is you are trying to say that your date actually has multiple months, multiple days, and multiple years:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(
  'dd/mm/yyyy H:i:s', 
  '01/02/2018 00:00:00'
);
```

So that action is expecting your input date to look like this:

```
'0101/0202/18181818 00:00:00'
```

But since your date did NOT fit that bill, it will return false as it fails to match the date to the format you provided.

**Your Request for a Fix**

The way to fix it, would be this instead (note a single `d` `m` and `Y` as per the [documentation of PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)):

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(
  'd/m/Y H:i:s', 
  '01/02/2018 00:00:00'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You used format `'dd/mm/yyyy H:i:s'` which is not correct.

Use single letters such as:

- `d` to represent two digit day 01 to 31 or 1 to 31,
- `m` to get two digit month 01 through 12
- `Y` uppercase as four digit year 1977 or 2017
- `H` upper case as two digit hours  00 through 23
- `i` to get two digit minutes 00 to 59
- `s` to get two digit seconds 00 through 59

So correct format is `'d/m/Y H:i:s'`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php